# Mimicking xcode's build process through xcodebuild

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm looking to build + run my iphone xcode project totally outside of xcode.

Currently I'm using xcodebuild to build the project - which seems to build cleanly:

https://gist.github.com/8eadfb1acca4d101624b

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to replicate the same Build as done by xcode.  Rebuilding it leads to a bunch of syntax errors.

Are there other flags I should be passing xcodebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a problem with shared precompiled headers? Like, building different versions of a project on the same machine. Try stating "clean build" (or clean install, whatever you want to do) as build actions at the end of your xcodebuild call.